# Waking-up two threads with a Poco:Condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, poco, poco-libraries

using Poco 1.9.0-1 from MSYS2 under Windows 7 (64 bits).

I have one thread, signaling a Poco:Condition for three times, with a sleep of 300ms.

I have two threads using two diferent classes EvListenerA and EvListenerB, that extends from Poco::Runnable, and they are waiting the same Poco::Condition to show a message with std::cout.

With the first and second signals, there are no problems, but when third signal is launched, only the thread EvListenerA capture it correctly.

This is the code:

```
/*
 * main.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 6 jun. 2019
 *      Author: ccortiz
 */

#include <Poco/Thread.h>
#include <Poco/Runnable.h>
#include <Poco/Condition.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Poco::Condition condicion;
Poco::Mutex     mutex;

class GenEvents:public Poco::Runnable{
public:
    void run(){
        cout << "Launching GenEvents!" << endl;

        for (Poco::UInt32 i=0; i<3; i++){
            cout << "[GenEvents] Event_" << i << endl;
            condicion.broadcast();
            Poco::Thread::sleep(300); //Wait 300ms.
        }
        cout << "Ending GenEvents!" << endl;
    }
};

class EvListenerA:public Poco::Runnable{
public:
    void run(){
        cout << "Launching EvListenerA!" << endl;

        for (Poco::UInt32 i=0; i<3; i++){
            condicion.wait(mutex);
            cout << "   [EvListenerA] Receiving Event_" << i << endl;
        }
        cout << "Ending EvListenerA!" << endl;
    }
};

class EvListenerB:public Poco::Runnable{
public:
    void run(){
        cout << "Launching EvListenerB!" << endl;

        for (Poco::UInt32 i=0; i<3; i++){
            condicion.wait(mutex);
            cout << "   [EvListenerB] Receiving Event_" << i << endl;
        }
        cout << "Ending EvListenerB!" << endl;
    }
};

int main(void){
    Poco::Thread th1; //Hilo que genera 3 eventos.
    Poco::Thread th2; //Hilo que espera 3 eventos.
    Poco::Thread th3; //Hilo que espera 3 eventos.

    GenEvents  genEvents;  //Objeto que implementa el hilo generador de eventos.
    EvListenerA evListenerA; //Objeto que implementa el hilo receptor de eventos.
    EvListenerB evListenerB; //Objeto que implementa el hilo receptor de eventos.

    th2.start(evListenerA);
    th3.start(evListenerB);
    Poco::Thread::sleep(500); //Espera de medio segundo.

    th1.start(genEvents);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    th3.join();
}
```

This is the program output:

```
Launching EvListenerB!
Launching EvListenerA!
Launching GenEvents!
[GenEvents] Event_0
   [EvListenerB] Receiving Event_0
   [EvListenerA] Receiving Event_0
[GenEvents] Event_1
   [EvListenerA] Receiving Event_1
   [EvListenerB] Receiving Event_1
[GenEvents] Event_2
   [EvListenerA] Receiving Event_2
Ending EvListenerA!
Ending GenEvents!
```

Why I don't have my "[EvListenerB] Receiving Event_2" in the output?

What happens with EvListenerB and Event_2?

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, for me this is undefined behaviour. Reference states clearly that `Condition` is used together with `Mutex` or `FastMutex`. When `wait` is called `mutex` must be locked! - it is missing in your code.

Quotes from [reference](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Condition.html):

> A Condition object is always used in conjunction with a Mutex (or
>   FastMutex) object.

and

> Unlocks the mutex (which must be locked upon calling wait()) and waits
>   for the given time until the Condition is signalled.
>
> The given mutex will be locked again upon successfully leaving the
>   function, even in case of an exception.

So if you want to see descired output you have to call lock/unlock onto mutex:

```
    for (Poco::UInt32 i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        mutex.lock();  // <--- lock mutex
        condicion.wait(mutex);
        cout << "   [EvListenerA] Receiving Event_" << i << endl;
        mutex.unlock(); // <--- unlock
    }
```

do the same change for `EvListenerA` and `EvListenerB` classes.

First you are locking mutex. Then `wait` is called, it unlocks `mutex` and we are waiting until `condition` is signaled, then `wait` returns and mutex is locked again (before returning from `wait`). Before leaving out of scope of for loop iteration `unlock` is called.

Comment: I have tried your idea, and it works. Thanks. But I have played a little bit arround this... I guess that the right way to do it, is appending an attribute mutex for each evListener. This avoid the undefined behaviour, and works too. Thanks again